# Using Ruby CSV header converters

Tags: ruby, csv

Say I have the following class:

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesible :first_name, :last_name
```

and the following in a CSV file:

```
First Name,Last Name
John,Doe
Jane,Doe
```

I want to save the contents of the CSV into the database.  I have the following in a Rake file:

```
namespace :migration do
  desc "Migrate CSV data"
  task :import, [:model, :file_path] => :environment do |t, args|
    require 'csv'

    model = args.model.constantize
    path = args.file_path
    CSV.foreach(path, :headers => true,
                      :converters => :all,
                      :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') }
                      ) do |row|
    model.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

end

I am getting an `undefined method 'downcase' for nil:NilClass`.  If I exclude the header converters then I get `unknown attribute 'First Name'`.  What's the correct syntax for converting a header from, say, `First Name` to `first_name`?

Comment: Give the error fully *undefined method 'downcase'*, which help us to to know, on what object the method has been called.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Edited the question, it's on `nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Just add one entry there `:return_headers => true`. I didn't test, but hope it will work. If it helps, let me know, I will explain you all what happened.

Comment: Thanks, give me a few minutes to check it out.

Comment: That seems to be it.  Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After doing some research here in my desktop, it seems to me the error is for something else.

First I put the data in my `"a.txt"` file as below :

```
First Name,Last Name
John,Doe
Jane,Doe
```

Now I ran the code, which is saved in my `so.rb` file.

**so.rb**

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("C:\\Users\\arup\\a.txt", 
             :headers => true,
             :converters => :all,
             :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') }
           ) do |row|
    p row
end
```

Now running the :

```
C:\Users\arup>ruby -v so.rb
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
#<CSV::Row "first_name":"John" "last_name":"Doe">
#<CSV::Row "first_name":"Jane" "last_name":"Doe">
```

So everything is working now. Now let me reproduce the error :

I put the data in my `"a.txt"` file as below ( just added a `,` after the last column) :

```
First Name,Last Name,
John,Doe
Jane,Doe
```

Now I ran the code, which is saved in my `so.rb` file, again.

```
C:\Users\arup>ruby -v so.rb
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
so.rb:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It seems, in your header row, there is **blank column value** which is causing the error. Thus if you have a control to the source *CSV* file, check there the same. Or do some change in your code, to handle the error as below :

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("C:\\Users\\arup\\a.txt",
             :headers => true,
             :converters => :all,
             :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') unless h.nil? }
           ) do |row|
    p row
end
```

Comment: You're right, there was an extra comma somewhere, but the strange thing is, the code still needs your initial suggestion of `:return_headers => true` to work.  Otherwise it gives an `undefined attribute: ` error.

Comment: @jcm Then do add that, but without `:return_headers => true`, the code ran as expected here for me.

Answer (score 8):

A more general answer, but if you have code that you need to process as text, and sometimes you might get a nil in there, then call to_s on the object.  This will turn nil into an empty string.  eg

```
h.to_s.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
```

This will never blow up, whatever h is, because every class in ruby has the to_s method, and it always returns a string (unless you've overridden it to do something else, which would be unadvisable).

Answer (score 0):

Passing :symbol to :header_converters will automatically convert to strings to snake case as well.

```
options = {:headers => true, 
           :header_converters => :symbol}
CSV.foreach(filepath, options) ...
#<CSV::Row first_name:"John" last_name:"Doe">
#<CSV::Row first_name:"Jane" last_name:"Doe">
```