# Change header of specific column with Ruby CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

CSV headers can be converted with `header_converters` and lambda expressions, as shown in "[Using Ruby CSV header converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904614/using-ruby-csv-header-converters)". However, is there a way to specifically only convert say the first column, and leave the others untouched?

For example, assume my headers are

```
<random string>, head1, head2, headN
```

The value of `<random string>` may change between CSV files, and I'd like to change this header to some predetermined string, so that headers become

```
time, head1, head2, headN
```

Comment: It would be better if you supplied an example of the input CSV and the expected output CSV, rather than ask people to go read the other question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not find this documented in examples, only in the [source of `csv.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/csv.rb#L1713). Converters receive an optional second argument, [`field_info`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/csv.rb#L2192). According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/lib/csv.rb#L901), this is a `Struct` with the fields `index`, `line`, and `header`:

- `index`:  The zero-based index of the field in its row.
- `line`:   The line of the data source this row is from.
- `header`: The header for the column, when available.

So as an example, this will convert the first header to `"time"` and leave others untouched:

```
CSV.new(f, header_converters: lambda{|h, field_info| field_info.index == 0 ? "time" : h })
```